# How to replace multiple '\n's with single '\n'?

Tags: apex

How to replace multiple '\n's with single '\n'? More specifically, how to write regex to match multiple '\n's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex to match multiple `\n`s is

```
\n+
```

The plus (`+`) specifically matches 1 or more occurrences of the proceeding character.  You can see it action:

```
string t = 'hey\n\n\nyou.';
system.debug(t);
system.debug(t.replaceAll('\n+', '\n'));
```

Note the use of `replaceAll`.  Apex has three string replacement methods; they are all instance methods  :

- `replace(String target, String replacement)` - replaces all literal (not regex) occurrences of *target* with *replacement*.
- `replaceAll(String target, String replacement)` - replaces all occurrences of the **regex** *target* with *replacement*
- `replaceFirst(String target, String replacement)` - replace the first occurrence of the **regex** *target* with *replacement*